# HTML SVG line animation

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I make a dot line from starting begin to the end path (for example the `3` shape, with the dot line drawing from top to bottom)?

```css
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: showDiag 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showDiag {
  from {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg class height="200" width="200">
    <line fill="none" stroke="black" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" stroke-dasharray="5, 5" />
    </svg>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to do the fade out from top to bottom.

Comment: have you tried something? Please put it here.

Comment: You would need to create a **bunch** of keyframes in order to make a curved shape like in the number `3`.

Answer (score 0):

With a solid (not dotted) line it is quite easy. Here is a very good tutorial:

[Animated line drawing in SVG](https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/)

Answer (score 0):

> I bet all of you have seen that little trick where an SVG path is
>   animated to look like it's drawing itself. It's super cool. Jake
>   Archibald pioneered the technique and has a super good interactive
>   blog post on how it works. Brian Suda wrote about it on 24 Ways.
>   Polygon used it to great effect on a custom designed article and wrote
>   about it. Codrops has some neat examples.
>
> I have very little to add, except my brain just kinda figured it out,
>   so I thought I would explain it one more time the way it clicked for
>   me.

**here is something that i read and looks useful -** https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Comment: i have a question,there are a lot of numbers. How can i write it one by one... it is so hard. Doesn't it?

Comment: Here is an implementation of the CSS Tricks shape with a dotted line https://codepen.io/elliz/pen/prYqwx